# Prove $f(x)=\|x\|:V\to \mathbb{R}^1$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, vector-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $\| \cdot \|$ be the norm defined on the vector space V

Prove $f(x)=\|x\|:V\to \mathbb{R}^1$ is continuous, or provide a counter example to show it is not

Comment: I assume $V$ is a topological vector space of some sort? And that no relationship is necessarily assumed between the distance $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ and the topology on $V$?

Comment: Hint: reverse triangle inequality.

Comment: @FrogotALot Yes where our normed vector space is defined as $(V,\|\cdot)$ and the vector space $V$ is a standard linear space with the usual axioms holding, are you able to provide some incite on the continuity of $f(x)$?

Comment: @User8128 I will attempt this now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any vectors $x,y \in V$, by the triangle inequality
$$\| x \| = \| y + (x-y) \| \leqslant \| y \| + \| x - y \| \,\, \Longrightarrow \,\, \|x\| - \| y \| \leqslant \| x - y\|.$$

Replacing the roles of $x,y$ in the last manipulation results in $$ \| y \| - \| x \| \leqslant \| y - x \| \,\, \Longrightarrow \,\, - \| x - y \| \leqslant \| x \| - \|y\|.$$

Thus $$| \|x \| - \|y\| | \leqslant \| x - y\|.$$

In other words, $| f(x) - f(y) | \leqslant \| x - y \|$.

Answer (score 0):

A vector space with a norm is automatically a metric space. Let $x \in V$. So using the definition of continuity for a metric space with $\epsilon=\delta$ you get:

$\forall \epsilon>0, \forall y \in V, ||x-y||<\delta \implies ||x-y||<\epsilon$

Comment: Im not sure if I follow...